# Install4j "Copy files and directories" installer action does not copy the file directory path

Tags: install4j

I do a backup of the files that need to be replaced as part of the installation. For this I use the above action. However, it just copies the files in the child directory to the destination directory but not the directory hierarchy of the source to the destination directory. Example: I have a some files in this directory structure \dir1\dir2\dir3\files. It copies only the files under dir3 but not the \dir1\dir2\dir3. I need to preserve the directory structure in the backup. Can anyone help with this please?

I am using Windows 7 Enterprise.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the root directory in the action, i.e. the one containing "dir1". Then, it will copy the whole directory tree to the destination.

If you want to copy only parts of the directory tree, use the "Directory filter" and "File filter" properties.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Ingo. There seems to be a bug in Install4J. If the source file is directory, it creates the directory and when it come to files in that directory it recreates the same directory again within the earlier directory and copies the files into that directory. In above example, \dir1\dir2\dir3\file1.txt is the source the destination would be \dir1\dir2\dir3\dir3\file1.txt. dir3 is created twice. this is only when you pass a directory as the Source instead of a specific file. This is a major problem for us trying to workaround. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks very much.

Comment: I mean to say in the above comment  \dir1\dir2\dir3\file1.txt is the SOURCE directory structure but you pass  \dir1\dir2 to install4j above bug happens.

Comment: Please send me a small test case to support@ej-technologies.com